# Sorting a complex array of objects using a boolean attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have found a few answers to this question, but for some reason it hasn't worked for me.

I have a large array of objects that needs to be sorted by a boolean property (all the ones that are `true` need to appear first). The most popular answer I find is:

```
let myList = [
  {
    thing: <div>Something</div>,
    sortingAttribute: false
  },
  {
    thing: <div>Something else</div>,
    sortingAttribute: true
  },
  {
    thing: <div>Whatever</div>,
    sortingAttribute: true
  }
  .
  .
  .
]

myList.sort((x, y) => {
  return (x.sortingAttribute === y.sortingAttribute) ? 0 : x ? -1 : 1
})
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I have attempted to make a few variations of it, to no avail.

An alternative to this is simply doing:

```
myList.sort((x, y) => {return x.sortingAttribute - y.sortingAttribute})
```

However it also hasn't worked. I also attempted to use underscore's sortBy function, but nothing.

I wouldn't think this has anything to do with it, but prior to attempting to sort I do a `.map()` on another list to get `myList` as it is now. Would this somehow be the cause of the problem? Other than that it is pretty straight forward.

Here is the full function:

```
getMyList (basicArray) {
    let myList = basicArray.map((arr, key) => {
      const sortingAttribute = key > 2 // just used for the example
      // the real code would obviously generate a more random order of trues and falses

      // do other stuff
      return {
        thing: (<div key={key}>{stuff}</div>),
        sortingAttribute: sortingAttribute
      }
    })

    myList.sort((x, y) => {
      return (x.isQualified === y.isQualified) ? 0 : x ? -1 : 1
    })
    console.log('myList SORTED', myList)
  }
```

Currently that displays exactly the order that was spat out from the `.map()`
So for an array of size 5, we would have:

> false, false, false, true, true

Comment: Are you doing  `myList = myList.sort((x, y) => {return x.sortingAttribute - y.sortingAttribute})` ?

Comment: @Keith that worked! Thanks! If you want, but it as the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: based on your results you could just call array.reverse(), then your output would be true, true, false, false, false

Comment: @AzizJaved I did try that, yes. But didn't work either. Fortunately the other method seems to have worked with just the reverse of 1 and -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the delta of boolean value `b` and value `a`, because `true` becomes the value `1` and `false` `0` with an implicit casting to number with the minus operator.

```js
var array = [false, true, false, false, true, true, false, true];

array.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yup, silly me probably had them reversed. It worked! Thanks!